# Are there compiler options to minimize file size of binary for Opa web (or "cloud") apps?

Tags: opa

I have the simplest "Hello, web" web app written in Opa (see one line of code below):

```
server = one_page_server("Hello", -> <>Hello, web!</>)
```

I then compile this file (in my case named hello.opa) like so:

```
opa hello.opa
```

This generates a file `hello.exe` which is ~35Mb in size. I realize Opa packages a big punch in the binary, but is there anyway to get the size of the resulting binary file down if our app isn't utilizing all the its neat features? If so, how? I reviewed the options printed on `opa --help`, but did not see anything that appeared pertinent to this query.

Information about my environment:

- Operating system: OS X/10.7 (Lion)
- Opa version: S3.5 -- build 652

Appreciate any input.

Updated: @Bill mentioned using `strip`. I ran `strip` on the `hello.exe` binary file and it brought it down to 25Mb. Excellent suggestion (I had forgotten about strip) though I was hoping for something still smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `upx` and compare the result size with the one produced by strip. 7.3M on my Mac for this hello.opa.

You can use MacPort on your Mac to install it: `sudo port install upx`

Note that we have made a big website ( http://jetleague.com/ ) with OPA. I've checked on the server, and the binary is only 13M (upx-ed).

Don't forget that their is everything inside this binary. You can run it on any fresh server without any extra-installation (like Apache, Mysql, PHP modules...).

If you need to update your server, you can use `rsync` for fast updates.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to opa, but did you try plain old strip?

Comment: I did, it still is 25Mb though:( Figured it would need to be done at the opa compiler level to get smaller. Thanks though!